# wso2 ei 6.5.0 registry search is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I can't able to search registry files in wso2 ei 6.5.0 and it showing like "Your search did not match any resources" same is working in wso2 esb 4.8.1. Could you please some one give suggestion how to enable it.

[image: No files available here[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJeO8.png)

Comment: Can you browse through the registry and check whether your resources are available?

Comment: @Pramodya Yes it is available i verify 2 or 3 times. could you please tell me can you able to search in wso2 ei 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Registry search option is not working in EI 6.5.0

There is no way to enable it.